# How to add different constraints depend on iPhone screen size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

This is my xib file viewed as iPhone6/iPhone7,it looks good.

[image]

but if i turn it into iPhoneSE,it becomes abnormal.

[image]

Becasue the space blank doesn't change when the device changes,and i can not change the space constraint adapting to device without code.

Comment: Make sure to set your constraints right. [Read this](http://www.appcoda.com/auto-layout-guide/) guide for more information of how you do that.

Comment: Which of the gaps in views you want to flexible?

Comment: Did you try setting your view width and height proportional to VC view?

Answer (score 1):

Try following constraints:

[image]

**Output: iPhone 6/7**

[image]

**Output: iPhone SE**

[image]

Specify your requirements more clearly, so that I can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't have to add different constraints depend on iPhone screen size! since constraints works perfectly with any screen size

just make a simple fix in layout constraints:

**The problem:** 
So what I am see that you have a problem with UIScrollView height it seems you set a fixed height constraint for UIScrollView

**The Solution:** 
first you need to remove the height constraint for UIScrollView
second just add a height constraint to UISCrollView equal to parent screen height and give it a percentage

Note:
how to put percentage in constraint -> highlight the constraint and then from attributes inspector there is an attribute named *Multiplier* it takes value form 0.0 to 1

Comment: The UIScrollView's height has to depend on the inside ContentView only. So it's a wrong idea to give it an explicit height.

Comment: Sorry I am didn't mention the size of content view !, we talk about container size, at all giving explicit height for container view doesn't effect the size of it's content view

Answer (score 0):

You need to make constants for supporting all devices like this.

```
var SCREEN_WIDTH = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
var BASE_SCREEN_HEIGHT:CGFloat = 667.0
var SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH = max(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
var ASPECT_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_7 = SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH / BASE_SCREEN_HEIGHT
```

I suppose your base layout is iPhone 7 that is your design resides in iPhone 7 layout.

Now create a function which will help to update your constraint according to device. like this.

```
func updateConstraint() {
    topConstantOfYourLabel.constant = 10*ASPECT_RATIO_RESPECT_OF_7
}
```

Call this method in viewDidLoad and your layout is just fine.

**Note:**
For landscape mode you need to make some changes depending on your needs.I assume that you are supporting only portrait mode.

Comment: this code should works,i intended to use code to work around,but i want to find a way to archieve it just by IBoutlet